# How to prove if a relation is linear and invariant by translation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, linear-transformations, signal-processing, computational-mathematics

The input is the sequence $U_n$ and the output is the sequence $V_n$, and for all $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $V_n=U_n-U_{n-1} +3U_{n+1}$ .

How to prove if the relation between the input and the output is linear and if it is invariant by translation.

Comment: It is not *series* but *sequences*.

Comment: Sorry but i'm a french speaker i don't know how to translate mathematic terms well. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I suggest you define what you mean by the relation (between input and output) being linear (in one sense this is evident from the statement of your problem) and what is meant by "invariant by translation".  The latter seems not to refer to the relation between input and output but perhaps to one or the other sequence.

Comment: What i have written is exactly what my teacher asked me to prove, he gave me this example too ( Vn=max(Un,Un-1,Un+1) )

Comment: The fact that it is linear comes from the fact that if two other sequences are in relationship $V'_{n}=U'_{n}-U'_{n-1}+3U'_{n+1}$, then we have the same relationship $(V_{n}+V'_{n})=(U_n+U'_{n})-(U_{n-1}+U'_{n-1})+3(U_{n+1} +U'_{n+1})$ as well, and the same for a multiplication by a scalar value.

Comment: @JeanMarie can you give me an example for a multiplication by a scalar value? thanks

Comment: Do the same as for addition.

Comment: c Vn = c Un− c Un−1+3 c Un+1
 then 
c Vn = c (Un− Un−1+3 Un+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use capital letters to indicate sequences, lower indices to indicate entries in a sequence, and lower case letters to indicate scalars. I'll assume the sequences you are interested in are real valued. The space of all such sequences can be referred to as $\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}$. This is vector space under the right operations, which allows us to define a notion of linearity.

We can define addition as an operation that acts independently on each element.

$$(A+B)_n=A_n+B_n$$

Scalar multiplication can be defined similarly.

$$(cA)_n=c(A_n)$$

Now, let $f:\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}\to\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}$ be a function such as the one you provided. We say $f$ is *linear* iff it preserves both addition and scalar multiplication. That is, for any $A,B\in\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}$ and any $c\in\mathbb R$, the following hold:

$$f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$$

$$f(cA)=cf(A)$$

To prove these equalities for a function such as yours, we need to show that they hold at every index. Here's an example for proving the first equality.

> $$f(A+B)_n=(A+B)_n-(A+B)_{n-1}+3(A+B)_{n+1}$$
>   $$=A_n+B_n-A_{n-1}-B_{n-1}+3A_{n+1}+3B_{n+1}$$
>   $$=(A_n-A_{n-1}+3A_{n-1})+(B_n-B_{n-1}+3B{n+1})$$
>   $$=f(A)_n+f(B)_n$$
>   $$=(f(A)+f(B))_n$$
>   We see that $f(A+B)_n=(f(A)+f(B))_n$ holds for any index $n\in\mathbb Z$, therefore $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$.

Hopefully, proving the 2nd equality should be straightforward.

We can also define *translations* (or *shifts*) as a set of functions, which I'll call $T^k:\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}\to\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|},\ k\in\mathbb Z$, such that:

$$T^k(A)_n=A_{n+k}$$

By plugging this into the equations above, we see that translations are linear functions. Also, we can refer to a function as *translation invariant* if it commutes with translations. In other words, $f$ is translation invariant iff for any $A\in\mathbb R^{|\mathbb Z|}$ and any $k\in \mathbb Z$, the following holds.

$$f(T^k(A))=T^k(f(A))$$

Again, this can be verified by showing the equality holds at every index $n$.

Comment: Well explained, thank you very much!